# Facebook Login CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, facebook

`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in /home/a7456390/public_html/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php on line 1027`

I set everyting up and still cant login from facebook.

here is my code:

```
1026 if ($result === false) {
1027       $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
1028         'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
...          'error' => array(
             'message' => curl_error($ch),
             'type' => 'CurlException',
             ),
           ));
           curl_close($ch);
           throw $e;
1036     }
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry @Nate I Couldn't :/